# this question was migrated from AVP, it probably shouldn't have been

Tags: discussion, migration

[This](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22479/ae-imported-mp4-seems-to-be-missing-audio) is a question specifically about After Effects. After Effects isn't really a sound design tool. People using AE are more likely to be concentrating on the video than the sound, and people asking AE questions are more likely to be looking at AVP. There's no After-Effects tag on SD, there is on AVP, there's no mp4 tag on SD there is on AVP.

I think this belongs back on AVP.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  I moved it back to AVP.  Like @TimPost said, flagging them with 'other' will be the best way to get the mis-tagged errors moved back to AVP.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hand full that were not quite appropriately tagged on AVP that got caught up in the mass migration of nearly 700 questions. AVP used certain audio meta tags to differentiate content between audio and video (part of the reason why video really needed a home of its own).

Prior to grabbing these *by tag* so that I could feed them to the mass migration tool, I did go through them and remove the tag in quite a few places where it was inappropriately used, or perhaps when audio was only a *tangential* part of the question.

These are being fixed now. If you see one, flag it for moderator attention, select 'other' and then simply say "send back to avp". You can also drop them [in the project chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12614/sound-design-avp-merge-project) where I and many of the moderators are camping out while this is in the works.

Sorry about the noise - fortunately, in the context of how many got sent over, it's not too many.